# How to put data point labels on a plot in Julia

Tags: plot, julia

I want to plot my data in a particular way like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb5KU.jpg)

in particular I want to know how to attach the labels arounud the points

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

```
using Plots, Random
vals = rand(10,2)
p = scatter(vals[:,1], vals[:,2],xlim=[0,1.1])
some_labels=randstring.(fill(5,10))
annotate!.(vals[:,1].+0.01, vals[:,2], text.(some_labels, :red, :left,11))
p
```